# Wordpress media uploads result in unwanted https url

Tags: php, wordpress, https

I recently installed Wordpress 4.2.1 using a https url for my site.  About halfway into working on my site I discovered that when I uploaded images they would have a url with https in it like the following in the attachment details:  "https://www.example.com/wp-uploads/2015/04/image.jpg"

This url is not editable from the attachment details and I did not intend for my site to use https all the time.  I only wanted to use https for wordpress administrative tasks.  How can I have new media uploads use a url containing http?

Comment: I found a workaround. The relative images url plugin for wordpress removes the protocol from a new image that is inserted into a post. Images that were posted prior to the plugin's installation need to have the url manually edited or reinserted.

The plugin can be found [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/relative-image-urls/faq/).

I am still interested in a solution that doesn't require the plugin if anyone has one.

Comment: Did you find the reason? I have the same problem and apparently the plugin is not fixing the problem either...

Comment: @Raffo I didn't find the root cause. I'm hoping someone might have an answer.

Comment: The recent update to 4.2.2 seems to have resolved the issue. Now uploaded media is using http.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still happening for me on WordPress 4.2.3. Stranger still, my test site and live site are both on 4.2.3, but it's only happening on the live site. If I find a cause or solution I'll post it here.